# Is there a way to set 'Disabled = false' of electron-simple-updater

Tags: electron, quasar

I'm wanna set up auto-updates features in my Electron App build in Quasar. So I come across with electron-simple-updater.

https://github.com/megahertz/electron-simple-updater#checking-for-update

I fail to implement it as the auto-updates just can't seem to work. Due to 'disabled' option always set to true, just like stated in the documentation.

I try

```
updater.setOptions({
    "url" : "...",
    "disabled" : false,
});
```

Then when I

```
console.log(updater.checkForUpdates());
```

It display

```
Update is disabled
```

It's not working. I'm able to set any options other than 'disabled'

## Is there any way to force 'disabled = false'?

By the way, my environment is macOS v10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> Your application must be signed for automatic updates on macOS.

To enable automatic updates on MacOS your app must be signed.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. I tested in windows env, it shows the same message with the same settings, which is 'Update is disabled'. 
But I will try to find out how I should sign for automatic updates, or any help you could provide would muchly be appreciated.